# Android Spawn Multiple ImageView with Different Position

Tags: java, android

I'm creating an android application and I want to spawn multiple imageviews with same image and different position.I have a class for the image and with for loop I created 15 images and add it to ArrayList and set differen position with enhanced for loop ,but now they are 15 images with only one position and it seems like 1 image.Look at my code

This is the main class

```
private ImageView pumpkinImg;
private int imageY = 50;
private int imageX = 50;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_second);

    pumpkinImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pumpkin_second);

    ArrayList<Pumpkin> pumpkins = new ArrayList<Pumpkin>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 15; i ++){
        Pumpkin p = new Pumpkin(pumpkinImg);

        pumpkins.add(p);
    }
    for(Pumpkin pmk : pumpkins){

        pmk.setV(pumpkinImg);
        pmk.setPosX(pmk.getV(), imageX);
        pmk.setPosY(pmk.getV(), imageY);

        imageX += 20;
        imageY += 20;
    }


}
```

And here is my pumpkin class

```
public class Pumpkin {

private int x;
private int y;
ImageView v;

public Pumpkin(ImageView v){


}

public void setPosX(ImageView v,int posX){
    v.setX(posX);
}
public void setPosY(ImageView v,int posY){
    v.setY(posY);
}

public ImageView getV() {
    return v;
}

public void setV(ImageView v) {
    this.v = v;
}
```

}

Here is my XML FILE :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:text="@string/level_two_welcome"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/pumpkin_second"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/level_2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: did you achieved this? Even am facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

you are only creating one Instance of an ImageView and are referencing exactly this instance!
In addition, you have to add the Images to a proper Android-layout!

The current layout you're referencing in your Activity-class is

```
R.layout.activity_play_second
```

Can you provide, which layout this is?

It seems, that this layout holds an ImageView

```
R.id.pumpkin_second
```

that displays the pumpkin-image. I think, this is not what you want!

Put the dynamic creation of all ImageViews into your for-Loop:

```
//create ImageView from drawable resource
ImageView iv = new ImageView( this );
iv.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.my_resource );

//add to main layout
( (ViewGroup)this.findViewById( R.layout.activity_play_second ) ).addView( iv );
```

Please find a complete code sample - Make sure to adjust the resource identifiers!

```
    setContentView( R.layout.my_layout );
    ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup)findViewById( R.id.my_container_id_in_my_layout );

    ImageView iv = new ImageView( this );
    iv.setImageResource( R.drawable.my_drawable_resource );

    ImageView iv2 = new ImageView( this );
    iv2.setImageResource( R.drawable.my_drawable_resource );

    view.addView( iv  );
    view.addView( iv2 );
```

You need an ID of an Container view that lies INSIDE your layout-file.
Here is an example layout file ( res/layout/my_layout.xml ):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/my_container_id_in_my_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helps?

Greetings

Christopher

Comment: I put it into a for loop but I can't use addView(iv),it says add cast to method reciever and I added this cast and it's still wrong :(

Comment: Hi. The result of this.findViewById must be cast to ViewGroup:
ViewGroup myLayout = (ViewGroup)this.findViewById( R.layout.activity_play_second );
myLayout.addView( myImageView );

Comment: This is the error : The method addView(ImageView) is undefined for the type View

Comment: It throws an exception

Comment: well .. I think you will have to post your res/layout/my_layout.xml file in order for us to solve it :)

Comment: Okay Here is my XML file of my layout

<!-- language: lang-xml-->

Comment: Look the question I typed it

Comment: Okay but what means my_container_id_in_my_layout - my layout id or my imageview id ?

Comment: I've added the correct layout file to the post.
You need to specify and identify a container-layout inside of your layout-file. You can then add dynamic content here. :)

Comment: Yea it works I put the code in a for loop but it's the same effect like the image is only 1 not 10 or more